# Race condition in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

How does Meteor prevent from race condition when two users update the same collection? I suspect it has to do something with Fibers.

The code below is from the todo list tutorial. What if two users toggle a checkbox at the same time. How  does meteor prevent race condition. Can you point me to the right spot in the source code?

```
Template.task.events({                                                                                               
  'click .toggle-checked'() {
    // Set the checked property to the opposite of its current value
    Tasks.update(this._id, {
      $set: { checked: ! this.checked },
    });
  },
  'click .delete'() {
    Tasks.remove(this._id);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Meteor doesn't do anything in your scenario, it's up to MongoDB to handle it. and that depends on which storage engine you're using.

WiredTiger allows for record-level locking. check here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#how-granular-are-locks-in-mongodb

> For most read and write operations, WiredTiger uses optimistic
>   concurrency control. WiredTiger uses only intent locks at the global,
>   database and collection levels. When the storage engine detects
>   conflicts between two operations, one will incur a write conflict
>   causing MongoDB to transparently retry that operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an edge case. Meteor is bound to Mongodb and Mongodb implements locking when it is updating. Someone who's also here in SO should confirm this. Also, in my experience I didn't experience this problem.

Anyway, if you also want to rate-limit calls to a certain method (limiting calls to a method in the server), you could use a https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/ddp-rate-limiter package from atmosphere! When you use this, you will be able to limit calls to a method for the current user. A nice guide is available in meteor chef blog: https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/rate-limiting-methods

Let me know..